# What is this "Sign in to <sitename> using Google prompt called?

Tags: google-signin

I've recently been seeing this all over the web these days:

[image: What is this widget sort of thing called?]

Earlier we used to have sign in with Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc., buttons using OAuth and what not but this something new as this is very much aware of all the accounts that you are logged in with on Google in your browser and all you have to do is to just click the click on the one you want to use.

I am curious to know what is this called, What technologies does it use and how can I incorporate this into my own websites?

Answer (score 0):

Google uses OAuth 2.0 only for third-party authentication using its accounts.

But the JS that is responsible for initiating this flow is improvised. It now detects the state of signin, and shows the list of accounts that are already logged-in or were logged-in at this device. The user selects one of the accounts, and from there the sign-in process is the same standard OAuth flow.

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/session-state